# Android : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I have a verry strange behavior today with my app.

My app works fine when i launch it from Eclipse.

But when i install my app on a device from Google Play, i get the following error :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.rss.cupofnews/com.rss.main.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.rss.main.MainActivity

I don't understand why i get this error when i install my app from Google play and why i don't get this error when i install my app directly on the device from Eclipse.

Maybe a problem with my packages ?

Here is a piece of code of my androidManifest.xml :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rss.cupofnews"
    android:versionCode="7"
    android:versionName="1.6">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 

    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
        android:allowBackup="true">

        <activity android:name="com.rss.utils.WebBrowserViewActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.rss.utils.LicencesView"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.rss.preferences.bibliothequeActivity"></activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.rss.main.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

And here is a screenshot of my explorer file in eclipse :

[image]

What is the problem ?

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Did you configure ProGuard properly? https://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

Comment: I never configure this tool. It can resolve the problem ?

Comment: It may help. A common reason why a class is not found in production, when it is found in debug, is that ProGuard renamed it.

Comment: Try turning off proguard to see if this makes a difference. Did you submit your app to Google Play before testing it on a real device?

Comment: Could you be colliding with com.rss.* package from another app? (your test app, for instance?)

Answer (score 0):

Check your proguard settings, it might be renaming your main class when you do the build for submitting to the play store.

try adding 
-keep public class com.rss.main.MainActivity

Comment: I never use this tool. I will try to add this flag

Comment: If you are using eclipse check your project.properties and it will point to the location for the config file.  Mine has proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt Depending on your project you may need to add some other exemptions (like for ActionBarSherlock).